# How to enable a button again after a specific amount of time has passed?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I currently have a check-in button in my app which is currently working but I want to disable it after the first check-in and enable it again after 30 mins.  I know I can just do:

```
checkInButton.enabled = false
```

and then re-enable it again, but how can I set it up so it automatically re-enables itself after 30 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds, target: self, selector: Selector("enableButton"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func enableButton(){
   self.checkInButton.enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

call perform selector

```
[self performSelector:@selector(enableButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
```

or use timer :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:seld selector:@selector(enableButton) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]
```

1.5 is on second.
You must implementing the called method

```
-(void)enableButton{
    checkInButton.enabled = true
}
```

Comment: Is there a swift way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

**@try this**

```
let seconds = 60.0 * 30   // Number of seconds in 30 mins
let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

            dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    self.checkInButton.enabled = true


            })
```